Accessing local variables in Groovy functions
Why is this not working in Groovy ...
def x = 42

def fn() {
  println(x) // Error: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: x
}

fn()

... while this is working?
def x() {
  return 42
}

def fn() {
  println(x())
}

fn()

Remark: You can use https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-groovy-online to test the Groovy scripts.
